# Is this a DDoS attack? What can I do to stop?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

In my apache access log, I'm getting... hundreds of these per minute

```
my.server.ip.address mysite.com:80 27.145.135.56 - - [14/Dec/2016:07:37:30 +1100] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

After about a minute or two, my Apache crashes.

I tried to add that IP address to my iptables

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 27.145.135.56 -j DROP
```

But when I look at iptable entries it somehow becomes below

```
DROP       all  --  cm-27-145-135-56.revip12.asianet.co.th  anywhere
```

But the bigger problem is that I'm still seeing the apache log entry.

What can I do to resolve this? Right now, I need to restart Apache to get my site up and running again. FYI, I'm on Linode.

Comment: Have a look [serverfault.com/questions/476318/apache-access-log-x80w-x01-x03-x01/476339](https://serverfault.com/questions/476318/apache-access-log-x80w-x01-x03-x01/476339)

Comment: I would told you use fail2ban

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking no this is not a DDOS attack. DDOS attacks are originated from many different IP addresses (The first D means Distributed).

I am not even sure that you are under any kind of attack.

You can block the requests from a single IP either using the firewall rule that you mentioned (be sure that iptables is up and running) or you can block this IP using an apache .htaccess file like this:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 27.145.135.56
allow from all
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you perhaps configured 'SSLEngine On' inside of a VirtualHost setup on port 80?

\x16\x03\x01 appears to be associated with SSL errors and the line from you error log references port 80.

I would check your Apache configuration for any mistakes in your SSL configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rate limiting in iptables... A new rule with something like the below will only allow 20 connections per IP address:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 20 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Comment: "_A new rule with something like the below will only allow 20 connections per IP_" So, only 20 IPv4 addresses and 20 IPv6 addresses? Or, did you mean per IP address, not per IP (Internet Protocol)?

Comment: I meant 20 connection per IP Address. Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my original post. Thanks.